# Laravel 8: Cannot set PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-8

I am trying to set the PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT to 10 seconds, but the change is not persisting. The timeout is stuck at 2 seconds no matter what I try.

config/database.php:

```
        'mysql' => [
            // ...
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 10,
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Even after running this command to clear the config cache, it's not taking.

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Also tried setting it in the contoller:

```
PDO::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

But Laravel throws an Error:

> **Non-static method PDO::setAttribute() cannot be called statically**

Even though setAttribute is a static method in the PHP docs.  Shouldn't have to set it this way anyway, but just the configuration setting is not persisting.

Comment: [`PDO::setAttribute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) doesn't appear to be a static method. Note [the description](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php#refsect1-pdo.setattribute-description) states it "_Sets an attribute on the database handle._" and the [Class synopsis](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php#pdo.synopsis) shows it as `public setAttribute(int $attribute, mixed $value): bool` without the `static` keyword, like it does for [`getAvailableDrivers()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php)

Comment: Interesting... while it doesn't appear to be affiliated with the StackExchange network, this appears to be cross-posted on [databaseanswers.net](https://www.databaseanswers.net/question/laravel-8-cannot-set-pdoattr_timeout/) by a user [Clara](https://www.databaseanswers.net/profile/clara/), as well as [solveforum.com](https://www.solveforum.com/forums/threads/solved-laravel-8-cannot-set-pdo-attr_timeout.869087/) where it shows `[Solved]` before the title but I don't see an answer 

Comment: You're right, maybe a bot or somebody copy-pasting? This is the only place I posted this question.

Comment: ‍♂️  Have you tried debugging which options get sent through? e.g. in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php after `$options` is assigned [on line 19](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php#L19) one could log the options being passed to the connection with a line like `\Log::info(__METHOD__.' options:' . var_export($options, true));`. I'm attempting to get the `LoginTimeout` option working with the SqlServerConnector - it appears to work in windows but not mac...

Answer (score 0):

The PDO method `setAttribute` is [not static](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) but needs an instance.

Use `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 10)` directly on the connection object.

```php
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 10);
```